# How to get Odds Ratios after MICE followed by pool()

Tags: r

I would like to carry out a logistic regression analysis where I predict the odds of an outcome (i.e., suicide-this is a binary outcome (0/1)) based on the type of childhood trauma (i.e. sexabuse-this is a binary variable (0/1)) reported.

I have some of missing values in  my dataset (i.e., data.noid) so I employed `MICE` with the following commands:

```
set.seed(123)
imp20 = mice(data.noid, m=20, printFlag=FALSE, maxit = 50, 
                                               seed=2525, control = list(maxiter = 500))
```

It has worked well for my data. so I proceeded with the glm analysis followed by the `pool()` and `round()` functions to obtain the association between my outcome (i.e., suicide) and childhood trauma (i.e., childhood sexual abuse). I fitted the following:

```
fit.mi20 = with(data=imp20, exp = glm(suicide~ sexabuse , family = binomial))
combFit = pool(fit.mi20) 
round(summary(combFit),2)

Results: 
                   est   se     t     df Pr(>|t|) lo 95 hi 95 nmis  fmi lambda
(Intercept)       -2.01 0.32 -6.24 130.08     0.00 -2.65 -1.37   NA 0.14   0.13
sexabuse2          0.50 0.53  0.95 153.93     0.35 -0.54  1.54   NA 0.07   0.06
```

I was hoping you could kindly advise me how I can obtain ORs (rather than 'est' as presented at this moment). I will be grateful for any advice and guidance.

Comment: The estimates are on the log odds scale, so exponentiate the estimates

Comment: Hello user2957945, thank you very much for your comment. Please forgive my ignorance and perhaps lack of language proficiency (English is not my first language) but could you kindly elaborate a little bit more on how to exponentiate the estimates in this case. To be honest with you, I am a novice in such analyses and I do not think I have come across this concept. I am very grateful for your time and help.

Comment: `exp(cbind(OR = coef(fit.mi20), confint(fit.mi20)))` according to these references [reference1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/logistic-regression-in-r-odds-ratio) and [reference2](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/), should give odds ratio.

Comment: You are using logistic regression , so are modelling on the log odds
scale, that is log(p/1-p) = b_0  +  b_1x. So to get results on the odds scale ((p/1-p))
you need to exponentiate. This gives (p/1-p) = exp(b_0)exp(b_1)x - an increase in 1 unit in x
leads to an exp(b_1) times increase in odds. You can get these values by transforming the summary table:
  `s = summary(combFit) ; cbind(exp(s[, c("est", "lo 95", "hi 95")]), pval=s[, "Pr(>|t|)"])`

Comment: @hNu, thank you very much for your comment; however, I get the following error which I do not fully understand: 
[exp(cbind(OR = coef(fit.mi20), confint(fit.mi20))) 
Error in vcov.default(object) : 
  object does not have variance-covariance matrix]